# difference comparison variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, charts, visualization

i want to make a bar char which can compare 2 variables in the same object using R, example for dataframe like this

```
 data.frame(Unit = c("unit1", "unit2", "unit3"),
            Aktual = c(1500, 2200, 3000),
            Target = c(1600, 2100, 2900))
```

my expect the chart can be like chart in Kutools feature in excel.

Comment: "Kutools for Excel is a handy Excel add-in with more than 300 advanced features" - I think you need to be more specific than "chart". Can you provide an example chart?

Comment: difference arrow chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a ggplot barchart you need to transform the data into "long" format. I use the pivot longer function and specify that the Unit variable is to be excluded from the transformation. Then I pipe into ggplot, and specify the x y and fill color aesthetic attributes. Finally I make an assumption that you want side by side columns (dodged) for comparison:

```
df<-data.frame(Unit = c("unit1", "unit2", "unit3"),
           Aktual = c(1500, 2200, 3000),
           Target = c(1600, 2100, 2900))
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Unit) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Unit, y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image: column chart]